# Multi level menu not showing up correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Mega menu which show up two level of menus and it works fine with two level but i need to add level 3 as show in image below, level three breaks the design and `Grand Child One` & `Grand Child Two` menu which are showing up in a wrong manner

Image below show how it is showing up right now & how it show come.

Fiddle Example http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/33/
[image]

I have been struggling with this issue for some time and i am not able to get it right.

I would appreciate help in on this one.

**UPDATE**:

if any HTML Change is required to level 3 then it is okay for me.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">

    <!--
<nav id="menu" class="menu">

<nav id="nav" class="nav">
-->
      <nav class="nav-wrapper" id="nav">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li> <a href=""> Home   </a> </li>
          <li>
            <a  href="#"> Parent One </a>
            <div class="dropdown has-panel" style="min-height: 130px;">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"> Child One</a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img Child One]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child one of parent menu one.  This is child one of parent menu one.  This is child one of parent menu one.  This is child one of parent menu one.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">  Child Two  </a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img Child Two]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child Two of parent menu one. 
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dropdown has-panel" style="min-height: 130px;">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a  href="#">Grand Child One</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                          <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[Grand One]" class="media">
                          <span class="media-caption">
                            This is  Grand child one of Child One. This is  Grand child one of Child One. This is  Grand child one of Child One.
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a  href="#">Grand Child Two</a>
                        <div class="dd-panel">
                          <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[Grand Two]" class="media">
                          <span class="media-caption">
                            This is  Grand child Two of Child One. 
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">  Child Three  </a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 5]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child Three of parent menu one.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#">  Parent Two   </a>
            <div class="dropdown has-panel" style="min-height: 130px;">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">  Child One  </a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 6]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child One of parent menu Two.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">  Child Two  </a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 7]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child Two of parent menu Two.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">  Child Three  </a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 8]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child Three of parent menu Two.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                 <a href="#">  Child Four  </a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 9]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                     This is child Four of parent menu Two.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a  href="#"> Parent Three</a>
            <div class="dropdown has-panel" style="min-height: 130px;">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"> Child One</a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 10]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                     This is child One of parent menu Three.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#"> Child Two</a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 11]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                     This is child Two of parent menu Three.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a  href="#"> Parent Four</a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 12]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child One of parent menu Four.
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a  href="#"> Parent Four</a>
            <div class="dropdown has-panel" style="min-height: 130px;">
              <ul>
                <li>
                 <a  href="#"> Child One</a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 13]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                     This is child One of parent menu Four. 
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a  href="#"> Child Two</a>
                  <div class="dd-panel">
                    <img alt="Image" src="http://placehold.it/100x60&text=[img 14]" class="media">
                    <span class="media-caption">
                      This is child Two of parent menu Four. </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a  href="#"> Parent Five</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a  href="#"> Parent SIX</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to do a full answer but did not have time - the grandchildren are actually under child 2, causing some of the problems. Also, if you put a rule along the lines of ul ul div.dropdown{position:static; margin-left:0} that will get you part of the way there.

Comment: I will try  you tip, meanwhile i am also trying to make it work with css. I hope i get lucky.

Comment: You should include the relevant html and CSS in the question itself

Comment: I Have included Fiddle example also. anyway if that will help then i will add that too.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown has-panel" style="position:relative;width:inherit;margin:0">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a  href="#">Grand Child One</a>
```

i commented few lines of js and added some but even i don't remember what all i changed check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/936zB/4/)
I guess this is what you wanted. There might be some hover issues you just have to fix your height

Comment: It is close to what i am looking for but the level 3 menu image & text starts next to the level 3 menu is their a way it can show up from top as the level two menu image & text shows up.

Comment: here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/936zB/5/) the reason behind that is when you say postion:absolute to dd-panel it takes in realtion to the parent container which has a position set. So you need to give a -ve top